# How to generate mongo indexes via mongoTemplate

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Using spring data mongodb

Have a class for mongo document

```
@Document(collection = "Samples")
@CompoundIndexes({...})
public class Sample {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Index(sparse=true)
    private String field1;

    @Index(unique=true)
    private String field2;
}
```

Need method to remove all records in collection. For this, I use

```
mongoTemplate.dropCollection(Sample.class);
```

but in this case I loose all indexes on this collection. So I need to recreate all indexes.

There is a method

```
this.mongoTemplate.indexOps(Sample.class).ensureIndex(...);
```

But I need some index definition as a parameter to use this method.

**Is any way to recreate all document indexes using class annotations?**

Comment: `this.mongoTempalte.remove(null, Sample.class);` looks like a solution. But... I'm not sure...

Comment: `this.mongoTemplate.remove(new Query(), Sample.class);` - this works